# Get data Amadeus API Flight low fare search

Tags: amadeus

I need parameters to get data that contains `stops` array. I tried about 100 different combinations, and i didn't get any response that returns `stops` array in results.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this, please provide your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having stops is not that common and it usually depends on the distance between origin and destination. For example, having London as origin and Sydney as destination:

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=LON&destination=SYD&departureDate=2019-08-01&nonStop=false&returnDate=2019-08-28
```

You can check in the response that most of the segments contain stops:

```
"stops": [
    {
        "iataCode": "HKG",
        "duration": "0DT1H0M",
        "arrivalAt": "2019-08-28T12:00:00+08:00",
        "departureAt": "2019-08-28T13:00:00+08:00"
    },
    {
        "iataCode": "DOH",
        "duration": "0DT1H0M",
        "arrivalAt": "2019-08-28T14:00:00+03:00",
        "departureAt": "2019-08-28T15:00:00+03:00"
    },
    {
        "iataCode": "BAH",
        "duration": "0DT1H0M",
        "arrivalAt": "2019-08-28T16:00:00+03:00",
        "departureAt": "2019-08-28T17:00:00+03:00"
    }
]
```

Where *stop* means that an aircraft lands for refueling, for instance, but passengers don't necessary get out of the plane.

Comment: Thank you alnacle for your answer. :)